# jquery zebra-striping: how to ignore nested table from radiobuttonlist

Tags: jquery, asp.net, zebra-striping

I'm using jquery to zebra stripe a table, and it's working fine - except that there's a radio button list that is also getting the striping applied.

My table has

```
<table class="stripeMe">
```

The query is

```
$('.stripeMe tr:nth-child(odd)').addClass('odd');
```

The problem when one of the even rows contains an asp.net radiobutton list (which is rendered as a single-row table) it also gets the highlight.

Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify children using the [`child-selector`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/):

```
$('.stripeMe > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd)').addClass('odd');
```

...and be sure to *explicitly* include a `<tbody>` element in your markup if you haven't.

Currently you're using the [`descendant-selector`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/), which selects *all* `<tr>` elements no matter how deeply nested under `.stripeMe`.